# Sequences and probability of appearance

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I thought I had an idea of how to do these, then I started reading some other similar questions, and now I'm not sure I'm doing them right.  Can someone just let me know if this is the right approach?  This isn't really covered in our book or in the lectures, so I'm trying to extrapolate from the limited examples that we're given (the book is on applied statistics and dedicates a measly 3 total pages to counting methods).

The question is:
Suppose that a mechanic needs to schedule three oil changes, four engine diagnostics, and five brake jobs. Assume that all schedules are equally likely.

Determine the probability for each of the following:

1. All engine diagnostics are completed first.
2. The schedule begins with an engine diagnostic.
3. The first and last jobs of the day are engine diagnostics.
4. The first two jobs of the day are engine diagnostics.

My original approach to this was to figure out how many possible schedules there were.
I got 27,720.
$$\frac{12!}{3!4!5!}=27,720$$

Then I looked at how many different schedules I could make given the constraints.

I.e. for all engine diagnostics completed first, I have 4 openings filled, so I have 8 remaining openings to fill.

$$\frac{8!}{3!5!}=56$$

So, then I found the probability for one of these 56 schedules out of the possible 27,720.

$$56/27720=.00202$$

Is this the right way to do this type of problem?

Comment: Well, it depends on what counts as a schedule.  Since there are $12$ different service tickets, I would say there are $12!$ different possible schedules.  Your calculation of the probability is correct, however.  As long as your definition of a schedule is the same in the numerator and denominator, you get the right probabilities.

Comment: Understood. That was actually a side discussion with the prof. I.e. is each service distinguishable or indestinguishable. Just another sanity check, for 3 and 4, it's the same probability? Since each service event is independent, order shouldn't matter. I think. Do I have that right?

Comment: Yes, the answer should be the same for $3$ and $4$.